# Java Spring anonymous bean without parent

Tags: spring, javabeans, parent, anonymous-types

I try to understand code:

```
<bean id="topBean" class="com.topBean" >
    <property name="helpbean" ref="helpBean" />
    <property name="topFolder">
        <bean parent="someparent">
            <property name="propertyName" value="value1"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I try to find parent bean with name "someparent" but without success.
Is it allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be a bean called `someParent` somewhere in the context, or in a parent context. It's not valid otherwise.

Remember, contexts can themselves have parent contexts. Beans in a child context can refer to bean in their parent contexts.

Comment: I am sure that bean with name "someparent" not exists.

Comment: @user710818: If your context loads OK, then the bean does exist. End of story.

Comment: I think I am near to understand. Enclosing bean ("topBean") class has property with type"someparent". And this property has value value1.